# Appending matrices

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

Suppose I have a matrix. I delete an entire row and after doing so, I want to append the deleted row to the reduced matrix. How can I do this?

```
import numpy as np
A=np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
A1=np.delete(A,1,0)
A2=A[1,:]
np.append(A1,A2,0)
```

But this is showing error.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Did my answer solve your issue? Did you run into other problems?

Answer (score 1):

You can try `vstack` instead: *Stack arrays in sequence vertically (row wise).*
http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html

```
In [33]: np.vstack([A1, A2])
Out[33]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [7, 8, 9],
       [4, 5, 6]])
```

Comment: It fails for both 0 and 1. Since it is a 3x3 matrix initially and after deleting a row, I reduce it to a 2x3 matrix. Now I want to append the deleted row so that it once again becomes 3x3.

Answer (score 1):

When you do `np.delete` it returns the array without the deleted row, not the deleted row. So your `A1` has actually two rows instead of one, and that's why it's failing.

To achieve what you want, this should do it:

```
A1 = A[1]
A = np.delete(A, 1, 0)
result = np.append(A, A1[np.newaxis, :], 0)
```

and this `result` will contain:

```
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [7, 8, 9],
       [4, 5, 6]])
```

Was this what you wanted?

Note the use of `np.newaxis` is necessary to make the single-row array A1 of the same shape as the array to append (because `np.append` requires arrays to have the same number of dimensions).

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
def move_row_to_end(A, row):
  return A[range(row) + range(row + 1, A.shape[0]) + [row]]

A = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]])
print move_row_to_end(A, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

when appending keep the arrays in the same dimension

```
A=np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
A1=np.delete(A,1,0)
#a2 must be the same dimension as a1
A2=[A[1,:]]
print(np.append(A1,A2,axis=0))
```

output:

```
[[1 2 3]
 [7 8 9]
 [4 5 6]]
```